How to access hosts by hostname when using Windows Wireguard
I setup Wireguard on a Windows desktop (hostname WINDOWS11).  I use an iPhone to test Wireguard.  I have a standard Linksys router that functions as DNS on my network.  It is a consumer router.
Once connected, I cannot ping WINDOWS11 by hostname.  I can reach it instead by its by IP address.
I can reach the router by hostname, that came from the factory like this.  I have no way of altering my DNS records on this router.
I've set the DNS of my client config to the internal IP address of my router but it does nothing.
How can I reach hosts on my network by hostname with Wireguard on Windows?

mDNS probably. Which is broadcast and doesn't work across L2 segments.

So you mean like this "WINDOWS11" is your wireguard "server"? And it is connected to the LAN of the router, which has one of its port forwarded to this desktop? (And your iPhone connects to the wireguard via the router's public IP through cellular network?)

@vidarlo On Linux you can use a extra "stub" of systemd-resolved for the WG network. IIRC it will use LLMNR (and maybe also mDNS) as its "upstream" when handling unicast DNS requests from the WG clients. I'm not sure if there's anything else (on Linux or Windows) that has similar capability. Also, FWIW, I think Wireguard interfaces at least by default has multicast support disabled, so even multicast traffics from a client to a server (or vice versa) won't make it to its "only" destination. (Certainly not client to client since that's somewhat like "across L2 segments".)

@TomYan - yes that is correct.  Port forward goes to WINDOWS11 internal IP and I use dynamic dns to reach my router.
In another test, I purchased a router with Wireguard VPN server built into it.  I continue to get the same result:  I can reach WINDOWS11 by ip address and not hosotname.

I have a similar (to what I described in my comment) setup but the server is a RPi (Linux) host and the client is an Android phone. I also use the DNS server/forwarder on my home router as the DNS server on the client, and because of DHCP (or the DHCP reservation record I configured on the router, idk), I can resolve my RPi's hostname (which is the same as the one I use in the record) on my phone, but the IP is obviously gonna be the RPi's LAN IP. Because the RPi has Linux on it, I have no problem accessing it from my phone with any of its IP addresses, but I don't know if it's also the case for Windows.
My point is, if your router works similarly as mine, and if iOS works similarly as Android with respect to hostname resolution, "WINDOWS11", the wireguard "server", might be the only LAN host that you cannot access using hostname, simply because you are "expected" to reach it with its wireguard IP address. It works for the other LAN hosts because they belong to another network anyway, and Windows will just happily forward the traffic for you as it does for those that destined at your home router.
It could be a "policy" posed by the Windows firewall as well. I mean, on Linux if you want this kind of behavior, what you need to do would be to set up firewall rules that check whether the destination IP address is the address configured on the corresponding interface.
If you really need things to work for "WINDOWS11" as well, you probably need a DNS forwarder that has a record for it (but forward requests for other hostnames to the router's) specifically for the WG clients.
